# What does "envacuuming" mean?

Tags: meaning, nonce-words

Here's a passage from the novel, *The Road*, by Cormac McCarthy:

> They picked their way among the mummied figures. The black skin
>   stretched upon the bones and their faces split and shrunken on their
>   skulls. Like victims of some ghastly **envacuuming**. Passing them in
>   silence down that silent corridor through the drifting ash where they
>   struggled forever in the road's cold coagulate.

What is "envacuuming"?

In the Polish version of the book, it is translated as "enwakuumowanie" and that's not even a real word.

Comment: It's not even a real word in English either, but most likely you can guess the same meaning from that Polish translation - *"suctioning from the inside"*. It doesn't make a *lot* of sense - it's largely a creative writer exercising poetic license, in a "one-off" usage. Too Localised for ELU, I think.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No problem, feel free to close the question. There aren't many neologisms in the book, so I thought it was an actual words that I just couldn't find in the dictionaries.

Comment: It's florid poetic style (using *mummied* instead of *mummified* is [effectively archiac](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mummied%2Cmummified&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)). So that's one odd usage already (his *"coagulate"* is another). I don't know if **en-** is still a productive prefix, but it doesn't feel like it to me - so it's odd to use it with a "newish" context like vacuum cleaners/pumps. I think the language is simply intended to be *strange, alien, unsettling*, reflecting the scene he's portraying.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’m almost thinking that *en‑/em‑* might still be productive. Not in words like *embroider*, *envelop*, *enchant*, *engross*, or even *embark*, where I agree it is fossilized. But there are so many OED entries that start with *en‑* or *em‑* and end with the past participle like *‑ed* or *‑en*, that I suspect it may still sometimes being used productively: *embattled, emmarbled, encysted, enhearten, enslave, entomb*. If the word is new in the last century or two, and has an identifiable root after the *en‑* or *em‑*, I think those are probably still somewhat productive.

Comment: @tchrist: Having trawled several pages of Google results for **+"em" +"en" prefix "productive" english**, I can't see any support for the idea that it's *still* productive. I think it was mainly used for creating verbs from nouns, but it seems to me we tend to just start using the noun *as a verb* today (in the rare event that we don't already have a verb form, perhaps because it's a new noun). And perhaps the highly-productive *-ise/-ize,* and *-ate* mean we just don't need it anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I may be more productive than most in my coinages by analogy with existing forms. Given *enshroud*, might as well have *enrobe* to go along with *disrobe*, and thence perhaps *enhelm* or *engoggle* as neologisms, but perhaps not *encap* or *enhat*. Hm, maybe also *ensweeten* as in *embitter*? Looks like *imperil* works for *endanger*, so there may be some Latinate substitution possible with certain words; I suspect those are all present in the originals, though, so *impute* and *dispute* aren’t the result of anything perceived as productive in English: we’ve no **pute* left.

Comment: @@tchrist: Suppose we're looking for a [new] verb with the meaning *"to turn into a hobbit"*. I think practically everyone would choose *"hobbitise"* over *"enhobbit"*. By the same token, there really are instances of **pumpkinise/pumpkinize** on the Net, but I can't find a single relevant instance of **enpumpkin/empumpkin**.

Comment: Novelists are not grammarians and actual write books. Just like any noun can be verbed, any noun can be transformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They picked their way among the mummied figures. The black skin
>   stretched upon the bones and their faces split and shrunken on their
>   skulls. Like victims of some ghastly **envacuuming**.

IMO, McCarthy is employing the prefix *en-* to conjure up a vision of corpses which have been vacuum-ed *from the inside*, causing their skin to stretch tautly, and faces to shrink. Ugh!

Answer (score 5):

In its entry for the prefix **en-**, NOAD says:

> **1** forming verbs (added to nouns) : **expressing entry into the specified state or location** (as in *engulf*)
>   **2** forming verbs (added to nouns and adjectives) : **expressing conversion into the specified state** (as in *encrust*, *ennoble*).

Given that information, I'd assume that the word meant that the victims were somehow put into a vacuum.  (Whether that alludes to a physical vacuum or a metaphorical one, I'd need to see more than the five words you've supplied in your post.)

Comment: [They picked their way among the mummied figures. The black skin stretched upon the bones and their faces split and shrunken on their skulls. Like victims of some ghastly **envacuuming**. Passing them in silence down that silent corridor through the drifting ash where they
struggled forever in the road's cold coagulate.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/alt.usage.english/DKwCUgYpYOA). Okay, I shouldn't have just copied that guy's guess at the meaning earlier. I still don't think it's a useful metaphor - how do *we* know what a person in a vacuum looks like? It's off-topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think it's a vivid word picture meaning that it looked like the people's insides had been sucked out by some sort of a vacuum, leaving behind just a skeleton with skin stretched across it.

Comment: @JLG: Okay - I agree! Even after finding and posting the context (which OP has now added to the question), I didn't really read it. Now I have, and yes - it's striking imagery taken in context, and in the spirit of a linguistically-competent (and co-operative!) reader. But interpreting artistic neologisms is still off-topic, imho.

Answer (score 1):

Real word or not, others have used the term before. E.g., Hugh Kenner to Guy Davenport in a letter of November 1963:

"Columbus knew he had hit a barbarous bit of China coast; later voyagers knew they had hit an annoyance, an obstacle on way to China. It was by a major effort of the Renaissance imagination that the obstacle was transformed in the New World. Hence Renaissance megalomania part of the U.S. birthright, leading to Jay Gatsby, who is an envacuumed Medici."